# The hamiltonian of single trapped ion model: ion trap quantum computer

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, quantum-computer, ion-traps

This question is related to the textbook, "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information written by M. A. Nielsen and I. L. Chuang.

I tried to derive a relation when we deal with a model system where a single ion is trapped. (page 317-318)

The free particle hamiltonian is given as

$$
H_{0} = \hbar \omega_{0}S_{z}+\hbar \omega_{z}a^{\dagger}a,
$$
which stands for two electron spin states and vibrational states from the harmonic potential generated from an ion trap.

And, the authors considers exerting electromagnetic field which gives the perturbation:

$$
H_{I} = -\vec{\mu} \cdot \vec{B},
$$
and they say that it can be approximated to

$$ H_{I} \approx \left[\frac{\hbar \Omega}{2} \left(S_{+}e^{i(\varphi-\omega t)}+ S_{-}e^{-i(\varphi-\omega t)} \right) \right] + \left[ i \frac{\eta \hbar \Omega}{2} \left\{S_{+}a+S_{-}a^{\dagger}+S_{+}a^{\dagger}+S_{-}a \right\} \left(e^{i(\varphi-\omega t)}-e^{-i(\varphi-\omega t)} \right)\right] $$

**I'm wondering if there's some missing terms of the above relation.**

The rest stuff is my derivation:

---

The given magnetic field owing to the EM field is 
$
\vec{B} = B_{1} \hat{x} \cos(kz- \omega t + \varphi),
$
and the magnetic dipole moment of atom is $ \vec{\mu} = \mu_{m} \vec{S}$.
Thus, the perturbation is the following:
\begin{align*}
H_{I} &= -\mu_{m}S_{x}B_{1} \cos(kz-\omega t + \varphi) \\
&=-\mu_{m} B_{1} \frac{S_{+}+S_{-}}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \left(e^{i(kz-\omega t + \varphi)} + e^{-i(kz-\omega t + \varphi)} \right) \\
&= \frac{\hbar \Omega}{2}  \left(S_{+}+S_{-} \right) \left(e^{i(kz-\omega t + \varphi)} + e^{-i(kz-\omega t + \varphi)} \right), 
\end{align*}
where $\Omega = -\mu_{m}B_{1}/2 \hbar$.

Now, I put $z = z_{0}(a^{\dagger}+a)$ because the space is quantized according to the harmonic potential, and assumed the Lamb-Dicke parameter, $\eta = k z_{0} \rightarrow 0$. 
Then
$$
e^{ikz} = e^{i \eta (a^{\dagger}+a)} \approx 1 + i \eta (a^{\dagger}+a).
$$

Put this to the original equation, then

\begin{align*}
H_{I} & \approx \frac{\hbar \Omega}{2} \left(S_{+}+S_{-} \right) \left\{ \left[ 1 +i \eta(a^{\dagger}+a) \right] e^{i(\varphi - \omega t)}+ \left[ 1 -i \eta(a^{\dagger}+a) \right] e^{-i(\varphi - \omega t)}  \right\} \\
&= \left[\frac{\hbar \Omega}{2} \left(S_{+}e^{i(\varphi-\omega t)}+ \color{blue}{ S_{-}e^{i(\varphi-\omega t)} + S_{+}e^{-i(\varphi-\omega t)} }+ S_{-}e^{-i(\varphi-\omega t)} \right) \right] + \left[ i \frac{\eta \hbar \Omega}{2} \left\{S_{+}a+S_{-}a^{\dagger}+S_{+}a^{\dagger}+S_{-}a \right\} \left(e^{i(\varphi-\omega t)}-e^{-i(\varphi-\omega t)} \right)\right]
\end{align*}

---

So, the above blue terms are missing in the equation from the book.

Did I make some mistakes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess I found the justification for the approximation.

If we see the hamiltonian in interaction picture, then

$$
H_{I}' = \frac{\hbar \Omega}{2} \left(S_{+}e^{i[\varphi-(\omega-\omega_{0}) t]}+ \color{blue}{ S_{-}e^{i[\varphi-(\omega+\omega_{0}) t]} + S_{+}e^{-i[\varphi-(\omega+\omega_{0}) t]} }+ S_{-}e^{-i[\varphi-(\omega-\omega_{0}) t]} \right)
$$

When the EM field is resonant $\omega = \omega_{0}$, only two terms are dominant.
$$
H_{I}' \approx \frac{\hbar \Omega}{2} \left(S_{+}e^{i\varphi}+ S_{-}e^{-i\varphi} \right)
$$

So, the blue terms may be insignificant if the authors tried to explain the qubit control in resonant region.

Also, it seems to be customary to omit these high frequency term. I find it's one of examples for rotating wave approximation.

Comment: Nice job answering your own question. This is one of the best ways to learn :-)